# IE 11 sub-domain CORS preflight request aborted

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cors

I've been struggling with this problem for a while now and will definitely appreciate any help.

Changed my server's config so it will "accept every request", everything works perfectly in Chrome, but IE is blocking my preflight requests.

Working example from Chrome:

[image]

here is how it looks when trying to send the same request with the same code in IE 11 (11.0.9600.17031)

Summary:
[image]

Details: (all other tabs are empty)
[image]

1. I've tried to investigate this problem using Fiddler but it seems like it changes few headers so when it's open the request succeed.
2. Tried to reproduce the problem using Postman/Fiddler but all requests succeed.
3. P3P isn't enabled in my browser (problem reproduce across devices)
4. Tried to call other services (such as mockable.io) and request succeed (**what makes me understand that the problem is somewhere in my server configuration)

My request is made via es6 fetch, with the [fetch polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) but problem reproduce with native `XMLHttpRequest` obj as well:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "...", true);

xhr.onload = function() { console.log("doesn't get called on IE"); };
xhr.onerror = function(e) { console.log("oh no.") };

xhr.send();
```

Error when performing request from console:

[image]

Error when performing request:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: crucially you do not mention which server this is. Also note that `xhr.send()` for a POST needs a payload argument, even if there is no data to post (although in that case, really, you shouldn't be using POST to begin with), so you want `xhr.send(null)` at the very least.

Comment: is request being made from page on `http` to `https` endpoint?

Comment: It's a Java server and the page is HTTPS. Thanks for the quick reply. Mike I'll try what you said, but I find it hard to believe that this is my problem.